# htaccess and URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a list of URLs such as,

`http://www.mywebsite.com/page.php?genus=A_GENUS&species=A_SPECIES&id=12345`.

I would like to write a .htaccess which permanently redirects visits to this form of URL to the following URL,

`http://www.mywebsite.com/species/A_GENUS/A_SPECIES`.

Is it possible to do this without having to manually list each species in the database?

I've tried to look it up but my head is in WordPress-Custom-Post-Type land and as such my brain isn't functioning properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Clarification**

Currently my .htaccess is completely empty. I am re-writing my website to use an entirely new CMS and this new URL format. The old URL format will cease to exist but all of the information will still be used.

We are quite highly ranked for a lot of species on Google and I would like visitors from there to be able to view the information they require despite the URL format changing.

These changes haven't occurred yet (still using a Sandbox environment for the new version of the site) and I'd like to make the URL changes just before I "go live" with the new version.

**EDIT 2: New site .htaccess**

The contents of the new site's .htaccess looks like this in its entirety:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sandboxfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sandboxfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**EDIT for Garmen's answer**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sandboxfolder/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} genus=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)&species=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ /species/%1/%2 [R=302]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sandboxfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sandboxfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Not sure if I've used RewriteBase correctly there, but it doesn't appear to function with or without it.

Regards,

Comment: What does your htaccess currently contain? Does the old url still work? Is the new url already being rewritten (internally) to the old one?

Comment: Sorry Gerben, I'll update my post accordingly.

Comment: Will the new CMS not use any htaccess? Are the url-parameters always in that order when links are created on the old site?

Comment: The new CMS will use htaccess, yes. I'll update my post again :) The URLs on the old site always take exactly that format, yes.

Comment: Asking clear questions is as hard as answering them :) See below for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} genus=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)&species=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /species/%1/%2? [L,R=302]
```

This one assumes a very specific order of query string parameters. So be warned. Also it assumes the names only contains plain letters, numbers, or dashes.

Change 302 to 301 when you are done testing. I used 302 because 301's are aggressively cached by browsers, making debugging very difficult.

**EDIT**: You should add this above the other rewrite rules you have, or it will not work.

**EDIT 2**: added a `?` at the end to remove the querystring. And `L` flag to prevent further execution.

Comment: That makes sense in my head and looks perfect, I hope! I'll give it a go now. Thanks very much for your assistance Gerben - once I've had a play I'll make sure you get the Correct Answer :)

Comment: Hi again Garben. It does work, but it adds additional information on to the URL: `/species/Parasphaerichthys/lineatus?genus=Parasphaerichthys&species=lineatus&id=1565`

Comment: In addition, when used above my WordPress rules, the code doesn't seem to work at all. Is this because WordPress is re-writing all files that aren't "index.php" back to the index page? Still, I put the code above those rules as you instructed, but the WordPress rules still appear to take precedence. I will update my original post to show you the way I've written the .htaccess in case it's wrong.

Comment: Placement is correct, but I notice your used `profile.php` not `page.php`. Try adding the L flag: `[L,R=302]`

Comment: Oh, Garben, one other thing: are these URLs case sensitive? i.e. if I have `Parasphaerichthys`, will that work for a /parasphaerichthys/ rewrite, or is that dependent upon my CMS?